# Add a new property to an object property

Tags: javascript

I need to write new properties for the comment property without erasing it.
This is my object now:

```
product:
{
  name: 'name',
  briefPDescription: 'text',
  details:
   {
     about: 'text',
     description: 'text',
     comment:
     {
         "text": 'text'
     },
     subDescription: 'text' 
}
```

What you need to write:

```
author:
{ 
    name: 'name',
    position: 'text',
    photo: '../avatar.png' 
}
```

How should it be:

```
product: 
{
  name: 'name',
  briefPDescription: 'text',
  details:
  {
     about: 'text',
     description: 'text',
     comment: 
     { 
         text: ''text',
         name: 'name',
         position: 'text',
         photo: '../avatar.png' 
     },
     subDescription: 'text' 
}
```

I did this:

```
product.comment = author;
```

But it deleted the `text` property.
How can I write new properties to the comment property without erasing it?

Comment: This shuld help....as it's already answered..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
product.details.comment = {...product.details.comment, ...author};
```

For more info about the Spread operator see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: You'd need to use `product.details.comment`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator syntax, to a) keep all the value that were already inside `product.details.comment`, and b) to add the values of `author`:

```js
var product = {
  name: 'name',
  briefPDescription: 'text',
  details: {
    about: 'text',
    description: 'text',
    comment: {
      "text": 'text'
    },
    subDescription: 'text'
  }
}

var author = {
  name: 'name',
  position: 'text',
  photo: '../avatar.png'
}

product.details.comment = { ...product.details.comment, ...author}

console.log(product)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
let product={name:'name',briefPDescription:'text',details:{about:'text',description:'text',comment:{"text":'text'},subDescription:'text'}};
let author={name:'name',position:'text',photo:'../avatar.png'};

Object.assign(product.details.comment, author);
console.log(product);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple tricky function got from typescript compiler;

```
    var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
    __assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
        for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
            s = arguments[i];
            for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
                t[p] = s[p];
        }
        return t;
    };
    return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Call:

```
product = __assign({}, product, { comment: author });
```